# Can webrat browser-automation tests be parallelised?

Tags: continuous-integration, selenium, webrat, browser-automation

Is there a facility similar to SeleniumGrid that I can use to run webrat (or other, similar framework) browser automation tests in parallel across a farm of coordinated agents?

Coordinated via TeamCity with rake?

Edit: We're looking at using cucumber+webrat to do functional and acceptance testing as described in [Testing ASP.NET Web Applications](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Testing-ASP-NET-Applications-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470496649/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1266572271&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on just this project actually. If you're working on rails, check out http://github.com/sgrove/spec_storm . It's only setup to run rspec + selenium tests in parallel, but it can be extended to others depending on the demand. And of course if you have any questions, I'm more than happy to help out. The more people using it, the happier I am :D